# GCOV no gcov file is generated

Tags: c++, c++11, gcov, gprof

I am trying to generate report for code coverage made via my unit test cases. I have added below flags for compilation and linking:

```
-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

The build systems compiles the source code and places the executable in different directories. The executable runs fine but no .gcov file generated.

```
C:\
C:\work\feature1\test\case\
C:\work\feature1\test\case\mytest.cpp
C:\work\build\features\CMakeLists.txt
....................................
C:\work\build\features\feature1\test\case\mytest.exe
```

How can I get code coverage report using gcov for mytest.cpp file?

Comment: Can you update your complete command for compilation?

Comment: I believe you added your flags somewhere, but you build not with them ;) I tested with the given flags and got .gcda .gdno files after running the executable.

Comment: The compilation goes fine except that the source code is split across cod base and the output during compilation are placed in different locations

Comment: I found the gcno file of my code in some other build directory with name "mytest.cpp.gcno" - so in all source code / executable and / .gcno files are all created in different locations in codebase. Putting them all in a same directory is not resolving to generate code coverage report

Comment: the -o option may help if your object fiiles do not live inside your source hierarchy?

Comment: Usually the coverage should be captured from within the project directory. Can you modify the build to generate the binary within the build directory?